# Insert variable value into Sql server through android and JDBC

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite, jdbc

I can not insert values to my SQL server 2008 from my SQLite database.Here is my code which i tried with lots of examples,but it failed.

```
dd =MainActivity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Sellapp", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
                   Cursor crs = dd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM customer", null);
                   while(crs.moveToNext()){
                          String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("id"));
                            String ucode= crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("cust_name"));
                            Log.v("executess", uname);
                            PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement("insert into item_device (im_code, im_desc) values (?, ?");
                            stmt.setString(1, uname);
                            stmt.setString(2, ucode);
                            stmt.executeUpdate();
                            Log.v("EExecutess", ucode);
```

in the variables uname, u code i have my database values. when I am trying to list values from these variables I can do it without any error. But when I am trying To insert whole table to SQL server I could't do it.I tried examples from other questions but no one fits my problem.please anybody help. Thanks in advance..

Comment: How do u connect to sqlserver, are u using api or different way?

Comment: @ Çağrı Using jdbc.I have a connection class. the connections to SQL server are working properly because the values in SQLite database is just fetched from the server.and now I am trying to insert on another table in the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself.I never thought it was very simple.I am posting my answer here.may be it will help someone..It can be done using [Batch execution](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JDBC/Batch/Insert_multiple_rows_into_database_with_Batch_Updates_and_check_the_result_in_Java.htm)

```
dd = MainActivity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Sellapp", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
Cursor crs = dd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM customer", null);

while(crs.moveToNext()){
    String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("id"));
    String ucode = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("cust_name"));
    String INSERT_RECORD = "insert into item_device(im_code, im_desc) values(?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = connect.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD);
    pstmt.setString(1, uname);
    pstmt.setString(2, ucode);
    pstmt.addBatch();


    // execute the batch
    int[] updateCounts = pstmt.executeBatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a webservice to handle the SQLServer access. You cannot access SQLSERVER directly from the mobile device.

Comment: I am accesing it from my system.and i can access the SQL server using jdbc driver.Selecting values from SQL server is working.and when I insert values as normal insert method it is inserting.my problem is that I can not insert  values resides in the variables..I dont know through which methode iI can do that.